# What edition of VS is installed by Unity and what are its capabilities?

Tags: unity, c++, visual-studio

My brother just installed Unity on my desktop, and it seems like it installed Visual Studio 2017 as well.

I was planning to install Visual Studio before this, so I was wondering what kind of version is this edition of VS? Is this like a bare-bones version? Does it work like a standalone version without lacking features? Can I use it just as a regular IDE to program in?

I typically program in C++, and I never used Unity before, so I'm not sure if this version of VS is only suited for Unity.

Comment: Did you try opening it up and seeing if you can compile & run a simple C++ application?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 No, I only found out that my brother installed it. I haven't had time to play around with it.

Comment: -1 "does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 2):

> so I was wondering what kind of version is this edition of VS?

It's most likely VS 2017 Community Edition if Unity is the 2017 version. AFAIK Unity 5 uses VS 2015, so that could be it too. You'd have to open it and see the version text at startup or in help / about section.

> Is this like a barebones version? Does it work like a standalone version without lacking features?

No. The Unity API is in there and it can be attached to Unity to work with it. Other than that it does what a standard VS 2017 does.

> Can I use it just as a regular IDE to program in?

Yep, there shouldn't be anything in there that would stop you from doing that.

> I typically program in C++, and I never used Unity before, so I'm not
>   sure if this version of VS is only suited for Unity.

It's not *just* for Unity, but still, you might need some additional stuff for C++ programming. The C# programming bit should work as expected and it did as far as I could see.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Visual Studio Community Edition which comes with Unity is pretty barebone. It only includes the core components and the package for Unity game development. So in that state it can not be used for much more than Unity scripting.

However, you can easily install the packages for many other programming language. Simply try to create a new project and in the selector for a project template click on "Open Visual Studio Installer". You can then download and install the C++ package. You will then have C++ project templates available.